# Get full details of files in TFS changeset

Tags: c#, xml, tfs, accurev

I am in the process of converting an Accurev repository to a TFS system.  I would like to check the work being done by comparing a changeset against an accurev transaction.  In accurev, I can create a giant xml document of all items in the stream at a given transaction using this command.

```
accurev stat -s [streamname] -t [transaction number] -a -fx
```

Which then gives me output like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AcResponse
    Command="stat"
    Directory="D:/Accurev/Core_14.0_Int"
    TaskId="190597">
  <element
      location=".\cspersonalci.bat"
      dir="no"
      executable="yes"
      id="242400"
      elemType="text"
      size="3078"
      modTime="1378234897"
      hierType="parallel"
      Virtual="6\10"
      namedVersion="Core_QA\10"
      Real="8032\3"
      status="(backed)"/>
</AcResponse>
```

Is there a corresponding command line option in TFS that will show the status of every single file in a branch for a given changeset?  I cannot use the changeset command as it will only show the files checked in and not the entire branch.